# Javascript objects keys without value

Tags: javascript, redux, javascript-objects

I am following the redux tutorial https://redux.js.org/basics/actions and having a hard time understanding the following code

```
export function addTodo(text) {
      return { type: ADD_TODO, text }
    }
```

So the function above returns the object `{ type: ADD_TODO, text }` and there are two things that confuse me.

1. what is the value of this object associated with the key `text`. If this value is undefined, then why not just return `{ type: ADD_TODO}` instead.
2. If `text` is a string, then shouldn't it be `{ type: ADD_TODO, [text]: *some value* }` instead?

Moreover, there are other functions like

```
function toggleTodo(index) {
      return { type: TOGGLE_TODO, index }
    }
function setVisibilityFilter(filter) {
      return { type: SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER, filter }
    }
```

Can someone explain this syntax to me?

Comment: `{ type: ADD_TODO, text }` is the es6 shorthand for  `{ type: ADD_TODO, text:text }` given a variable `text`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They're using [ES6 Shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Property_definitions) - If the intended key name is the same as the variable, then you can simply pass the variable

```js
let name = 'Jared';
let age = 19;
let literate = false;

let obj = {
  name,
  age,
  literate
}

/* Is the same as...
let obj = {
  'name': name,
  'age': age,
  'literate': literate
}
*/

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: There has to be a bunch of duplicates for this.

Comment: Almost certainly - Didn't think about that before writing the answer out